# Error when authenticating with a Keycloak cluster

Tags: keycloak

I've implemented a test environment to verify a clustered Keycloak authentication server with two Java web applications that need single signon. There are two Keycloak nodes in the cluster and there is Apache2 mod_proxy load balancer in front of them. I've followed the guidelines in the Keycloak documentation and everything seems to work fine, Keycloak logs report caches are started properly and syncronized:

> [Server:server-one] 11:28:04,298 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (thread-2) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [master:server-one|1] (2) [master:server-one, nucdev2:server-two]
>   [Server:server-one] 11:28:04,306 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (thread-2) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [master:server-one|1] (2) [master:server-one, nucdev2:server-two]
>   [Server:server-one] 11:28:04,318 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (thread-2) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [master:server-one|1] (2) [master:server-one, nucdev2:server-two]
>   [Server:server-one] 11:28:04,319 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (thread-2) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [master:server-one|1] (2) [master:server-one, nucdev2:server-two]
>   [Server:server-one] 11:28:04,321 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (thread-2) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [master:server-one|1] (2) [master:server-one, nucdev2:server-two]

The problem is that when authenticating from webapp, using the Keycloak Java adapter for Tomcat, I get a 403 Forbidden and looking at Keycloak log I see this error message:

> [Server:server-one] 11:33:30,700 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-3) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=test, clientId=customer-portal, userId=null, ipAddress=192.168.10.111, error=user_not_found, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=889ab790-0c3a-44ea-a1df-247ba501260f, client_auth_method=client-secret

Seems that the problem is related to clustering mode, since everything works fine in standalone mode.
Is there anyone who is able to provide an example of a clustered Keycloak installation with an external load balancer like mod_proxy?

Comment: Hi @remigio, have you found any solutions for this problem? I'm also stuck on the redirect problem

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Setting session affinity with the nginx ingress fixes the issue, but I suspect that's just a band-aid on some broken functionality. I suspect the AuthenticationSessions replication is not working correctly, but I don't see any indication that it's failing, and I'm not sure where to look or how to confirm it's the root issue.

Here are the nginx affinity settings I used on the ingress:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
```